# Why do I get 'webpack-subresource-integrity may interfere with hot reloading'?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

In my create-react-app I changed the render method of one of my components and now I am getting this in the chrome console:

> webpack-subresource-integrity: webpack-subresource-integrity may
>   interfere with hot reloading. Consider disabling this plugin in
>   development mode

Is this CRA related or webpack related? How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your build is using [webpack-subresource-integrity](https://github.com/waysact/webpack-subresource-integrity) which [should usually be enabled only in production mode](https://github.com/waysact/webpack-subresource-integrity#hot-reloading). (I'm the maintainer of that plugin.)

Add `enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` to the plugin's options and the warning should disappear.

For what it's worth, CRA [doesn't ship with webpack-subresource-integrity](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1231) because of their zero-configuration policy, so either you're using a CRA fork that does, or you've ejected and added our plugin manually.

If you think that the error message could be improved, [let us know about it](https://github.com/waysact/webpack-subresource-integrity/issues/new). If you're using a CRA fork, consider asking the maintainer to fix the plugin's default options.